# How to sort in ascending order

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

How to sort in ascending order these numbers in array exactly as String with one space separator and not converting to Int?

```
array = ["1 700", "50", "2 150", "2 100", "750", "3 250"]
array.sort(by: { $0 < $1 })
print(array) // ["1 700", "2 100", "2 150", "3 250", "50", "750"]
```

I need to be sorted as `["50", "750", "1 700", "2 100", "2 150", "3 250"]`

Is it possible?

Comment: `array.sort(by: { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").compare($1.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: ""), options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending })`?

Comment: The problem is that strings are compared alphabetically. If you want to compare them numerically, you have to convert them for the comparison.  Is the space separator for the thousands coming from the local parameters?

Comment: @Christophe Thanks for answer but Larme already did it )